# Como fazer para desindentar um código inteiro de uma vez so no python

Tags: python, indentação

Como o python é indent sensitive quando voce apaga uma estrututra por exemplo que ve que nao vai usar mais ele começa a dar erro por que o resto do codigo nao esta indentado como deveria, para indentar é so selecionar o codigo que quer e dar tab, mas para voltar ele todo para um espaço a esquerda de uma vez só, como fazer?

Comment: Isso não tem nada relacionado com Python, é  uma característica do programa que está usando para editar código. De qualquer maneira, pode [edit] o post e dar mais detalhes, sempre levando em  conta o [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).

Comment: A identação É o seu programa - se o "resto do código nao está indentado como deveria", você não tem um programa válido. Como você identa e desindenta blocos de código não é algo da lingugem, e sim, uma ferramenta do editor que você está usando pra programar. A grande maioria dos editores de código desindenta apertando "shift + tab" com o bloco selecionado. (alias, por issoo que a tecla tab, na maioria dos teclados, tem uma seta pra frente e uma pra trás, indicando que ela também desindenta)

Answer (score 4):

seleciona o codigo todo e aperta Shift+Tab.

Comment: Você deu a resposta certa e o pessoal negativa, parabéns aos envolvidos!